# How to substitute runtime variables into strings in c?

Tags: c, string

I am trying to write a c program that takes in a formula and substitutes user supplied values in place of the alphabetic variables.

```
Eg:
char formula[50]= "x+y+x"  //this is a string. Can also be given at runtime
char sub[50];//This is where my substitutions should go
printf("enter substitutes");
fgets(sub, sizeof(sub), stdin);
//user inputs x=1,y=2
```

Now, How do I substitute the values supplied in sub to the formula string?

Comment: Just to make sure you're aware first: C is not the best language for extensive string manipulation.

Comment: Yes I am aware that C is not the best language to easily manipulate strings but I am curious to know if such substitutions can be taken care. Just like python templates.

Comment: What C standard library gives you that closer matches your problem is `sscanf` to parse input and `sprintf` to combine values in output. If it is not enough you will have to build a parser, either *by hand* (like Gopi's answer) if grammar is simple enough or by using a parser library like lex+yacc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the expression to your char array formula using `fgets()` since you say it can be given during run-time.
2. Now get the other char array `sub` using `fgets()`
3. Assuming there is right match of number of characters needs to be replaced in the array `formula` matches the values passed by `sub`
4. Now parse your array `formula` use `isalpha()` and if it is then replace your character with value stored in `sub`.
5. Now you have.

> ```
> Formula = "x+y+z";
> Sub = "123";
>
> Formula = "1+2+3";
> ```

Check the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void) {
    int n,i=0,j=0;
    char a[20];
    char sub[20];

    fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);/* Get input from the user for formula*/
    n = strlen(a);
    if(n > 0 && a[n - 1] == '\n')
    a[n- 1] = '\0';
    fgets(sub,sizeof(sub),stdin);/* Get input from the user for sub*/
    n = strlen(sub);
    if(n>0 && sub[n-1] == '\n')
    sub[n-1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",a); /* Formula before substituting */
    while(a[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(isalpha(a[i]))/* If alpahbet replace with sub */
        {
            a[i] = sub[j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x+y+z
1+2+3
```

Comment: Generic Test Case`x=11, y=12, z=13`, `Output: 1+1+1`. However the OP has to be specific about this Implementation.

Comment: Thanks. WIll this work if two same alphabets are passed in? eg: formula:x+x+y sub:1,2 will it return 1+1+2??

Comment: also, what do these lines of your code do?
if(n > 0 && a[n - 1] == '\n')
    a[n- 1] = '\0';

Comment: @Tania No thats the reason I mentioned your input should match number of alphabets needs to be replaced

Comment: Oh Okay also, will it work if something like this is done?
formula=2*x+(y/2) ??

Comment: if(n > 0 && a[n - 1] == '\n') a[n- 1] = '\0'; why do we need these lines?

Comment: @Tania fgets() comes with a newline char so we need to supress it like this .

Comment: Oh wonderful. Thanks for explaining. Your logic works perfect on my specs now Im just wondering what to do for cases like x+y+x...